# How much would storage space increase when enabling system-versioned table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to enable a system versioning for some table in SQL Server. As I understand, the new history table would be created with the same values as current tables, plus I create two new datetime2 columns. Am I right that just enabling system versioning at least doubles the storage space?

Comment: If you empty and reload the table four times, theoretically you now have four copies of data in the history table. That's why clustered columnstire indexes are recommended for history tables

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand, **the new history table would be created with the
> same values as current tables**, plus I create two new datetime2
> columns. **Am I right that just enabling system versioning at least
> doubles the storage space**?

No.

The history table contains non current versions of rows so it is empty until you start deleting or updating rows in the main table.

So storage space will increase by whatever factor the addition of the two new datetime2 columns makes to row width and then depend on your rate of updates and deletes that invalidate existing row versions and cause rows to be stored in the history table.

NB: By default, the history table is `PAGE` compressed. You might also create it a clustered columnstore to achieve potentially greater levels of compression.